# FTP Connection Failing "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to connect to an FTP server to upload a file.  I am getting the "
Unable to connect" error.  If I use command line and open an FTP connection, I am able to connect. Not sure why I get error when connecting programatically.  Any help will surely be appreciated.

```
 FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://1.23.84.2");
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;                   

 request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user","password");

 // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.    
 StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(path);
 byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
 sourceStream.Close();
 request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

 Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
 requestStream.Close();

 FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

 Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", 
          response.StatusDescription);

 response.Close();
```

Comment: Your firewall might be blocking the ports. Try doing telnet to ftp port from a machine (not from the ftp server "ftp://1.23.84.2")... using command prompt
from cmd prompt, type: telnet ftp://1.23.84.2 21

Comment: you are correct!  If I telnet to the above ip address I get an error "could not open connection to the host on port 23"

Comment: @tranceporter, would i need to use a proxy to connect?

Comment: FYI, you should also have your `StreamReader`, `Stream`, and `FtpWebResponse` in `using` blocks, to ensure they get cleaned up whether or not an exception occurs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  Thanks for tip. I'll defiently wrap it in using block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after a few hours of trouble shooting, It was McAfee blocking the ftp port. had to temporarily disable the services on a local machine.

Comment: lol.. so it was the firewall (albeit MacAfee, instead of windows) blocking the port :)

Comment: Even though I am an admin on my machine, i still could not configure McAfee settings, stopping the service itself was the last resort.

Answer (score 3):

I think the FtpWebReqest needs to point to the target path, not just the server's address, like the following:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://1.23.84.2/myFile.zip");
```

The correct usage for FTP uploads in context of FtpWebRequest can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx).

Comment: If you look at my code, After I create the FTP request I read a textfile from my folder in a stream and then try to add it to the ftp server

Comment: Yes, but I think that you need to specify the name of the file on the server in WebRequest's Create method. If you take a look at the link I've provided, the sample indicates the same thing.

Comment: Yes, the file name must be specified in the FTP connection string.  I just came across this problem and adding the file name fixed the error.

Comment: I see, I just added a filename at the end, does it have to be a zip. my file is called for instance test.out. I just added that and still get the unable to connect issue :|

Comment: No the myFile.zip is just an example, use your name na of your file instead.

Comment: Thanks for the file name correction, it still does not resolve the connection issue though.